# test that list contain the same types of "objects" python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test that checks the return value of a function, the problem is that the function returns a list of tuples, where each tuple contains an integer and an object.

The object has floating point attributes so I want to use assertAlmostEqual there but something akin to "assertSameStructure" on the list.

So in pseudo-code what I want to do:

```
import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        result = foo(data)
        expected_obj = Bar(23.3,12.1)
        self.assertSameStructure([0,expected_obj],result)
        self.assertAlmostEquals(expected_obj,result[0][1])
```

Comment: `self.assertIsInstance(result[0], int)` and `self.assertIsInstance(result[1], Bar)`?

Comment: @Blender result could be any length container then

Comment: You could write the assert method you want. Loop over the expected and actual lists in parallel, and for each tuple, assert what you're interested in asserting about the elements. (Also, I think you're missing tuple parentheses in your call.)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few modules to help validate schemas instead of just testing for specific behaviors. Here's a simple example with [`schema`](https://github.com/halst/schema):

```
from schema import Schema

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertHasSchema(self, schema, obj):
        return Schema(*schema).validate(obj)

    def test_foo(self):
        result = foo(data)
        expected_obj = Bar(23.3,12.1)

        self.assertHasSchema([(int, Bar)], result)

        self.assertAlmostEquals(expected_obj, result[0][1])
```

Comment: This looks really nice but it does not seem to work :(

Comment: >>> from schema import Schema
>>> class Bar():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 2
... 

>>> class Bar():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 2
... 
>>> from schema import Schema
>>> class Bar():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 2
... 
Schema( Bar ).validate(Bar())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
raised TypeError('__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)',)

Comment: @user1443778: That seems to be a problem with your `Bar` class, not with the schema validation code. Does creating just a new instance of `Bar` throw an error? `Bar()`

Comment: >>> class Foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> Schema(Foo).validate(Foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/schema.py", line 170, in validate
schema.SchemaError: Foo(<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7f4a1e398b90>) raised TypeError('this constructor takes no arguments',)

Comment: @user1443778: Your classes should inherit from `object` in Python 2. There are subtle differences between old-style and new-style classes.

Comment: Okay, that helped in this example :). The problem is that the (external) class I want to test against has this problem

Comment: @user1443778: Looks like it's a bug in `schema`. They'll (hopefully) release the fix it in the next version. Meanwhile, you can either use the development version or write a simple version of that module yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain you only get a single result tuple back from your test you could simply test

```
self.assertAlmostEquals([(0,expected_obj)], result)
```

The only thing you're missing in your pseudo code is the brackets around the integer and the object.

alternatively you could implement assertSameStructure by running `isinstance(obj, tuple)` etc.